# USDBRL Forward Points

Tags: fx, forward-rate

USDBRL 1 year forward points are at 0.32 while SELIC (Brazil central bank rate) is at 13.75% and the CDI (interbank rate) is about 11.50% vs USD swap rates at around 4%.

What is the explanation behind this divergence between the forward rate implied by the interest rate differential and the actual rate.

Comment: What difference do you see between offshore non-delivery FX forwards, and onshore exchange-listed FX futures?

Comment: 0.32 should be 3200 points really. Do you refer to the difference between the FWD and Spot? I fail to see the actual problem. What do you expect?

Comment: The data source we are using refers to a 'point' as 0.0001 BRL. Is this correct? I.e if spot = 5.1913, the forward points are 0.32, it is also giving 5.1913 as the 1yr forward.

e.g see here https://www.fxempire.com/currencies/usd-brl/forward-rates

Comment: The data source is wrong. Points will be expressed as *10000. I can only guess but according to your link, the data vendor is xignite, which according to the [website](https://www.xignite.com/product/forex#/productoverview) does not offer FX outrights in its API but only Spot and points. These should be about 3200 - which will result in 0.32 being added to Spot, and a forward of ~5.5 which is in line with market quotes and covered interest rate parity. I suggest you look at a different source as yours clearly messes up the quotes.

Comment: Thank you this is useful!